# Python etl process guidelines using pandas and snowflake (possible data load routine?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, etl

I am new to the python-pandas environment and am looking for **general guidance** on building an extract, transform, load pipeline using python, pandas, and snowflake. Summary of the what I want to do:

1. connect to a snowflake database in python
2. execute snwoflake sql and store the resultant table in a pandas dataframe
3. extract from the original pandas dataframe specific data I need by making a new dataframe based on a select few columns
4. clean that new pandas dataframe to remove Nan values, empty or trailing/leading spaces and any data that doesn't necessarily fit the column data type. By this I mean I know which columns should be float, int, bool, or object. If a column should be float but its stored as bool because maybe the numeric values have commas (,) or dollar signs ($). I need to remove them.
5. once data is clean hit an api enpoint to run cals and get return data
6. insert return data into original dataframe and load that dataframe into snowflake

My problem is step 3 and 4 mainly because I do not want to edit the original dataframe so I am making a deepcopy. Once I make this deep copy I lose all the original datatypes in the new copy dataframe and they default to object because there is nan values in each column making the data non-homogenous. This is making it a headache to make more general purpose functions that can filter based on the dataframe datatype.

**Questions:**

I can either try to just remove the nan values and filter for characters in strings to make each column conform to the specific data type I want, or is there a way to force the data types I want when I make a deepcopy? Or is there a data loader routine or etl routine I should be following that's a best practice? Just lost on best way of going about this. The issue is just related to the datatypes all becoming object for columns.

Is there a better way of removing nan values, commas, dollar signs without dropping rows where I just fill missing or incorrect values with some default, or remove characters so i can properly cast the entire pandas dataframe column to the correct type?

I have the following functions to filter my data after I extract it from snowflake and store it in a pandas dataframe.

```
def extract_and_rename(df, org_column_names: list, new_column_names: list):
    '''Extract dataframe'''
    # df_extract = df[org_column_names]
    df_extract = pd.DataFrame(columns = org_column_names, data = copy.deepcopy(df[org_column_names].values))
    df_extract.columns = new_column_names
    return df_extract

def replace_null_with_dtype_kind(df):
    '''
    repalce all null values in dataframe based on numpy dtype.kind function
    which returns a character code (one of biufcmMOSUV) for identifying the general kind of data
    '''
    df_type_correction = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, data = copy.deepcopy(df.values))
    for col in df_type_correction.columns:
        # print(f'{col} - {df_type_correction[col].dtype.kind}')
        if df_type_correction[col].dtype.kind in 'OSU':
            df_type_correction[col] = df_type_correction[col].fillna('removed value')
        elif df_type_correction[col].dtype.kind in 'iufc':
            df_type_correction[col] = df_type_correction[col].fillna(-9999)
        elif df_type_correction[col].dtype.kind in 'b':
            df_type_correction[col] = df_type_correction[col].fillna(False)
        elif df_type_correction[col].dtype.kind in 'mM':
            df_type_correction[col] = df_type_correction[col].fillna(pd.to_datetime('1/1/2023'))
        else:
            print('Something went wrong')
    return df_type_correction

def dtype_set(df):
    '''try to convert data type values to numeric in pandas dataframe'''
    df_type_update = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, data = copy.deepcopy(df.values))
    for col in df.columns:
        df_type_update[col] = pd.to_numeric(df_type_update[col], errors='ignore')
    return df_type_update

df_sql = snowflake_query(QUERY)
df_fillna_values = replace_null_with_dtype_kind(df_sql)
df_correct_types = dtype_set(df_fillna_values)
```

The data in the df_sql dataframe would look like the sample below before being sent to one of the functions for some transformation or filtering:

|  | ID | OWN_ID | NAME | RECORD_TYPE | CREATED_DATE | PURCHASE_OFFER | MONTHLY_PAY | ADD_FEES | ASSUMPTIONS | ACCOUNT | TERMS | PRODUCT_TYPE | LEGAL_FEES | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ASD3N22KAS | MM2284 | JOSHUA TIES | SAAFF343 | 2020-05-23 | $122,235.67 | $2,461.49 | 150.00- | 8.0% | True | 24 | Direct | 10,100.15 | 1935 |
| 1 | H34J5BDYO8 | Nan | Nan | 34LVFDG5 | Nan | $498,323.14 | $2,314.18 | 275.00 | 8.0% | False | 36 | Mixed | 19,612.62 | 2005 |
| 2 | NWL38HXB57 | ZZY785 | KASWIK NHILE | POASM544 | 2021-10-01 | $3,745,648.45 | $1,425.20 | Nan | 8.0% | Nan | 60 | Open - acquisition | 2150.44 | 1999 |

Comment: Why don't you assign the dtypes to the new dataframe again? Something like this `df_copy = pd.DataFrame(df, dtype=df.dtypes)`

Comment: @Tasos I don't really follow. Would I be making a new copy of the deepcopy and then trying to assign data types then? So something like `df_extract = pd.DataFrame(columns = org_column_names, data = copy.deepcopy(df[org_column_names].values))  df_copy = pd.Dataframe(df_extract, dtype=df.dtypes)`  This could work but I would need to put all the datatypes for the new dataframe in a list of dictionary because the df_extract dataframe only contains some of the columns from the original dataframe. Let me know if I misunderstood, appreciate the help!

Comment: Not sure why you opted for `copy`. I am not aware if there is any big difference. But I think `df_extract = pd.DataFrame(df[org_column_names], dtype=df[org_column_names].dtypes)` will have the same result as the one you want to.

Comment: @Tasos so I went with the copy.deepcopy because I did not want to create object references and instead wanted a copy of the data. I could be wrong but my understanding was when you make a new dataframe through assignment like df2 = df1([col_name]) you are just creating object references to of df2 to df1. So when you update df2 than df1 gets updated. I wanted a copy of some select parts of df1 in df2 so that when i update df2 df1 is left untouched. But I'm not sure that this is necessary?